# result of array from query only shows one result?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm using a Ajax request to parse the data to jquery. Only the problem is that my query only shows one result! 
My query has more then one output and only shows one.

can someone help me out?

```
$query = "SELECT u.id, c.id, c.chatbox_id, c.subject FROM tbl_users u, tbl_chatbox c WHERE '".$user_id."' = c.id";
$rows = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $subject = $row['subject'];
        $chatbox_id = $row['chatbox_id'];
    }
    $array = array(
        "result" => "1",
        "id" => $id,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "chatbox_id" => $chatbox_id
        );

    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this also.

```
$query = "SELECT u.id, c.id, c.chatbox_id, c.subject FROM tbl_users u, tbl_chatbox c  WHERE '".$user_id."' = c.id";
$rows = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
 $i=0;
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$id = $row['id'];
$subject = $row['subject'];
$chatbox_id = $row['chatbox_id'];

$array[$i] = array(
"result" => "1",
"id" => $id,
"subject" => $subject,
"chatbox_id" => $chatbox_id
);
$i++;
```

}

echo json_encode($array);
}

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
$query = "SELECT u.id, c.id, c.chatbox_id, c.subject FROM tbl_users u, tbl_chatbox c WHERE '".$user_id."' = c.id";
$rows = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $chatbox_id = $row['chatbox_id'];

    $array[] = array(
    "result" => "1",
    "id" => $id,
    "subject" => $subject,
    "chatbox_id" => $chatbox_id
    );
  }

  echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: As soon as put my $array[] into the while loop the code won't work anymore.

Comment: If I change $array = array( .. to 
$array[] = array( .. it failed @lepanto

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

to this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

You were mixing mysqli's object-oriented and procedural styles, which can cause problems. The [`fetch_assoc` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) has more information.

Then, just put the `$array` assignment *inside* the `while` loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = array(
        "result" => "1",
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "subject" => $row['subject'],
        "chatbox_id" => $row['chatbox_id']
    );
}
```

After this `while` loop finishes, `$array` will be an array of associative arrays. You can use it like this:

```
foreach($array as $db_row) {
    echo "This row's id is " . $db_row['id'] . '<br />';
    echo "This row's subject is " . $db_row['subject'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Yes. And mixing the oo and the procedural style won't cause problems, only mixing mysql and mysqli.

Comment: ah, didn't know that. could have sworn i've had problems with that in the past, but it's been awhile since i've used mysqli.

Comment: saying "it won't work" doesn't actually convey any meaning. what error are you getting? what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: you'll have to do some debugging yourself then, or post your modified code.

Comment: You tested your query alone on db and it gives you more results? Why you dont need to use inner/left join in your query?